# ajax gif loader not working after second click, cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cakephp

im having a hard time with this issue. I made a site where a couple of links loads some content into a div using ajax. then i set a gif to tell ppl when its loading. The thing is it's working just fine, but in ie it only loads the first time i click these links, then it wont show up again the second time i click a link. here the code:

```
            <li><?php echo $this->Js->link('Sign up', array('controller'=> 'Users', 'action'=>'add'), array('evalScripts' => true, 'before' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),'complete' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)), 'update'=>'#center', 'class'=>'nav4')); $this->Js->get('.nav4'); $this->Js->event('click', '$(".crumb_navigation").html("Home > Sign up")');
```

And here is the view code:

```
<div class="center_content" id="center"><div class="center2">sdfadsf<?php echo $this->Html->image('/images/ajax-loader.gif', array('id' => 'busy-indicator')); ?></div></div>
```

So im wondering if any of you face this issue before, in which your loading gif only loads one time (in iexplorer) and the rest of the times you clic the link, nothing happens. But in any other browser works perfectly.

UPDATE:

I have tried everything by now, nothing seems to give me a break with iexplorer. I've used .on() .live() i have tried by writing this code by myself instead of using js helper but it only got worst haha. But not everything is lost my friends!!! i just had to disable cache from the appController and it started working!!!

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Currency->setVal('UYU', 'USD');
    $this->disableCache();
    $description = __('The place where you can ask for things and they will come to you!');
    $this->set('description', $description);
    $this->Auth->allow('index','view','account','add');
    $this->set('usuario', $this->Auth->user('role'));

}
```

tah-dah!